# Java: periodically sending data from thread to main class

Tags: java, multithreading

I have thread which download data from HTTP. I get it every 1 seconds to about 10 minutes using stream API.

After I receive data from HTTP server I need send this data to method in `MyMainClass`. How can I do that without static method? I don't like to use static method.

```
public class MyMainClass {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        GetData getData = new GetData();
        getData.start();        
    }

    public static void useText(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
        // do something...          
    }
}


public class GetData extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String text;

        /* Download text from HTTP and save it to "text".
         * Every 1 seconds to about 10 minutes using stream API.
         * text= "abc...";
         * If there are no errors, run method never exit.
         */
        MyMainClass.useText(text);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your method an instance method and create an instance of the class you can pass to your `Thread` instance

```
public static void main(String[] args) {            
    GetData getData = new GetData(new MyMainClass());
    getData.start();        
}

public void useText(String text) {
    System.out.println(text);
    // do something...          
}
```

In the `GetData` class' `run` method, you can then use the `MyMainClass` instance as a callback.

```
public GetData extends Thread {
    public GetData(MyMainClass instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    private MyMainClass instance;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String text;

        /* Download text from HTTP and save it to "text".
         * Every 1 seconds to about 10 minutes using stream API.
         * text= "abc...";
         * If there are no errors, run method never exit.
         */
        instance.useText(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!
But why you create new instance of `MyMainClass` in `GetData(new MyMainClass());`? How can thread use method from starting class (which start thread and main app) if working with new instance of `MyMainClass` class?

Comment: @martin I don't understand your question. The method is an instance method. You need an instance to invoke it on.